# how to make css grid items between two widths or span full width?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am placing x amount of grid items in a grid container. But for for this example let's say **two** grid-items.

Each grid-item should be between 300px-600px taking the max value and scaling down to minimum 300px when viewport gets smaller until it doesn't fit in a row and breaks into two rows with 100% width.

Now what happens is when the viewport goes to the point the grid-items stack on rows is that it does not span full width.

So something like:

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 600px);
}

.grid-item {
 ...
  ...
 height: 150px;
 
}
```

when viewport is large:
[image]

scaling down:

[image]

the following problems occur:

1. it stays at 600px and never scales down to 300px.
2. it does not span full width when it breaks into two rows.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try out flexbox!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-item {
  min-width: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

only add a max-width if you really need it or else there may be embty space at the and of the last item

Answer (score 0):

You can add **grid-template-columns: max-content;** into your grid layout.